# Trouble adding button and textview on the same view for android app - Illegal state exception

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button, illegalstateexception

I am a bit new to android apps and am trying to play around with them to get a better feel for how their work. Right now I am working on android's building your first app, where you pass a message to another activity. I want to display that message and have another button that could potentially go to another activity, but I cannot figure out my errors. I get an IllegalStateException - The child already has a parent, you must call removeView() on the child's parent first when I try to add the textview and the button to my relative layout. I have tried removing both of these functions but then my layout doesn't include the button. I am unsure as to why I am getting this error or if I am approaching this layout wrong. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code for my App

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        message = "The current address is " + message;
        textView.setText(message);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_address"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
        <activity android:name="AddressChange"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Fragment_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Back"
        android:text="@string/back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat files

```
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820): Process: com.example.app, PID: 820
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at com.example.app.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:35)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
06-04 15:22:55.380: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly add the TextView and Button to the layout? Aren't they already set in the xml?

Comment: Yes, they are both set in the XML. Only the TextView shows up automatically so I am trying to get both of them to show up at the same time.

Comment: Please post your xml. I suspect your button is set to be invisible...

Comment: @DerGolem Done. The XML I am using is fragment_display_message.xml

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see it - it was all in the same grey area...

Comment: I'd remove the two addView instructions and the following setContentView. Along with the LinearLayout declaration. Also, there's no need to set the button as visible, since it is already.

Comment: @DerGolem Hmm you're right. Sorry I will try to fix that real quick.

Comment: @DerGolem I think I misunderstood how to approach this. I couldn't see my button and thought that it was because I needed a new layout.

Comment: And? It's fixed, isn't it? - Wait... this is not only **USELESS**, it's **WRONG**: `backbutton.setVisibility(backbutton.VISIBLE);` Either comment it or use `backbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` (VISIBLE belongs to View, not to backButton)

Comment: @DerGolem I removed those lines after realizing that I didn't need to add the button in the first place.

Comment: This line seems to be still there: `backbutton.setVisibility(backbutton.VISIBLE);` did you remove it?

Comment: @DerGolem Updated to have my latest code. Currently, I am trying to manipulate the XML file to change the size of my text view and see if I can move the button around somehow.

Comment: @DerGolem And it worked! I was able to get the button to show up to the side. That's a start, so at least I know that it is there. It appears that my button and textview both try to show up on the same line. Is this because they are both set to wrap_content?

Comment: To move your button either use a RelativeLayout or some other layout (i.e.: GridLayout) that allows for View positioning

Comment: no. `wrap_content` says: "use only the space required to host your content (width|height)". Did you use a LinearLayout with an explicit orientation set to horizontal or a RelativeLayout or what?

Comment: @DerGolem First I was using a relative layout then switched to Linear. I left all the default values, which I believe was vertical.

Comment: For LinearLayout (which uses it), the default for orientation is vertical. RelativeLayout doesn't use it.

Comment: @DerGolem The relative layout was exactly what I needed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: OK, If you want the button UNDER your TextView (instead of to a side of it), use the attribute `android:below="#id/yourTextViewID"`

Comment: @DerGolem Awesome, I could see how my current layout could run into problems. I will make sure to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml layout does all of the adding of views for you.  By doing it yourself as well you create 2 parents for a single view, which is illegal.  Luckily in this case you're just doing work that isn't needed, so you can just remove those lines.

Comment: So my XML File should already show both the button and textview without me having to do anything. That's good to know I didn't realize that. Any idea why only the textview shows up?

Comment: Could it be that my Button is stuck behind my Textview?

Comment: It could be.  Try setting the width of the button to wrap_content, it may be that in trying to go fill_parent it goes off screen.  The other thing to do, if you want the text above the button, is to set the orientation of the linear layout to vertical.

Comment: Not in a LinearLayout. In this example, the LinearLayout is left to its default orientation (vertical). The textView is small enough to fit its contents height and under the TextView lies the button. With the default padding

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried setting it to wrap_content and it did not show up. I am going to try to put it at the bottom of the screen to see what happens.

Comment: @DerGolem Would this app be better suited for a Relative Layout? I wanted Linear so the button would show up right below the textview.

Comment: It depends. In this case, for such a simple layout, a LinearLayout can do the job. I ususally prefere RelativeLayouts for their versatility. I only use LinearLayouts when I need to use weights.